# DjangoUnicodeDecodeError while storing pickle'd data

Tags: django, unicode, pickle

I've got a simple `dict` object I'm trying to store in the database after it has been run through `pickle`.  It seems that Django doesn't like trying to encode this error.  I've checked with MySQL, and the query isn't even getting there before it is throwing the error, so I don't believe that is the problem.  The `dict` I'm storing looks like this:

```
{
    'ordered': [
        {   'value': u'First\xd1ame Last\xd1ame',
            'label': u'Full Name' },
        {   'value': u'123-456-7890',
            'label': u'Phone Number' },
        {   'value': u'user@nowhere.org',
            'label': u'Email Address' } ],
    'cleaned_data': {
        u'Phone Number': u'123-456-7890',
        u'Full Name': u'First\xd1ame Last\xd1ame',
        u'Email Address': u'user@nowhere.org' },
    'post_data': <QueryDict: {
        u'Phone Number': [u'1234567890'],
        u'Full Name_1': [u'Last\xd1ame'],
        u'Full Name_0': [u'First\xd1ame'],
        u'Email Address': [u'user@nowhere.org'] }>,
    'user': <User: itis>
}
```

The error that gets thrown is:

> 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 52-53: invalid data.

Position 52-53 is the first instance of `\xd1` (Ñ) in the pickled data.

So far, I've dug around StackOverflow and found a few questions where the database encoding for the objects was wrong.  This doesn't help me because there is no MySQL query yet.  This is happening before the database.  Google also didn't help much when searching for unicode errors on pickled data.

It is probably worth mentioning that if I don't use the Ñ, this code works fine.

Comment: This may not be that related to pickling per se, and may just be a unicode error in general. This might help http://www.amk.ca/python/howto/unicode

Comment: What would lead you to believe this might be a unicode error?  I'm fairly new to working with international characters, but everything appears to be encoded right by my eye.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With much thanks to @prometheus, I found a solution for this.  Basically you can use base64 to encode the output of `pickle.dumps()` before plugging it into the database.  You would then turn around and use base64 to decode the output of the database before passing it to `pickle.loads()`.

My code now looks like this:

```
## Put the information into the database:
self.raw_data = base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(data))

## Get the information out of the database:
return pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(self.raw_data))
```

Again, thank you @prometheus.

Answer (score 2):

That's a known problem, and there was a discussion about this on the [Python bug-tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue2980):

> I ran into this problem today when writing python data structures into a
>   database.  Only ASCII is safe in this situation.  I understood the
>   Python docs that protocol 0 was ASCII-only.
>
> I use pickle+base64 now, however, this makes debugging more difficult.
>
> Anyway, I think that the docs should clearly say that protocol 0 is not
>   ASCII-only because this is important in the Python world.  For example,
>   I saw this issue because Django makes an implicit unicode() conversion
>   with my input which fails with non-ASCII.

Comment: If you'd like to rework the answer I posted, I'd much rather give you the rep for finding the answer.

Comment: I'm fine, thanks. That's basically the code I'm using myself.

Answer (score 1):

I see no need to do so. Normally, it should be possible to store any binary data in a database.

A worse problem is that pickling is not safe - if the database could get its data from anywhere, it could get malicious pickling data.